# has_many :through in fixtures in rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to set up some has_many, :through objects using fixtures for testing in rails 3.1.

If you look at the documentation on the association as an example, I want to know how to assign assemblies to parts. The only way I've found to do it is to explicitly create the manifest object in it's own file, but if I'm happy with the defaults on that model and all I want to specify are the part/assembly id's then is there a way to do it directly?

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has_many-through-and-has_and_belongs_to_many

I want something like:

```
my_assembly:
    parts: my_first_part, my_second_part
```

This works if you do HABTM, but not when you have the explicit join model.

Answer (score -50, accepted):

Never, ever, use Rails fixtures for anything.

I'll repeat: *Never, ever, use Rails fixtures for anything.*

They are dangerous, cumbersome and make your tests leak state. They are unsuitable for writing proper tests. At best, you get tests that look as if they are properly written, but have hidden dependencies. The Rails team got this feature 100% wrong, and I wish they'd remove it from Rails so people wouldn't be tempted to use it.

Instead, install [factory_girl_rails](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl_rails) and use factories to create your testing records on demand:

```
Factory :assembly, :parts => [Factory(:part, :name => 'first'), Factory(:part, :name => 'second')]
```

Comment: +1 for useful advice, but i'm going to leave this question open as I'd still like to know whether syntax exists for what I had in my original question

Comment: It exists. I think you'd have to use what used to be called Foxy Fixtures (from the name of the gem that pioneered them before they went into Rails core). But just don't ever bother.

Comment: @spike I never meant to imply that it was. :)

Comment: I wasn't the down voter either.  I am curious here as to whether you've a source (or care to explain) what you mean by fixtures "are dangerous, cumbersome, and make your tests leak state."

Comment: @JohnLockwood When using fixtures, it is easiest to define lots of fixtures that get loaded for all your tests. This is *dangerous* because it puts lots of unnecessary records into the DB, which may cause false positives in your tests -- in other words, the DB state *leaks* between tests. It is also *cumbersome* to work with fixtures because they are defined in a separate place from the tests. The proper way to do this is to start from an empty DB and use factories to create a few records for each test, right in the test code itself. Does that answer your question?

Comment: I downvoted for "Never, ever, use Rails fixtures for anything."  That's silly advice.  I've used fixtures for some projects, factories for others and both methods have their pluses and minuses.

Comment: @pcg79 I'd be curious to hear what you think the advantages of fixtures are, but the fact remains that I -- along with many, if not most, experienced Rails developers -- believe that there is *no* proper use case for fixtures, for the reasons indicated above, and that factories are always the better option. I'm trying to find a single advantage of fixtures over factories, and I can't.

Comment: I'd be shocked if the "experienced Rails developers" at, say, 37 Signals agree w/ you.  In any case, you asked why the downvote and I told you.  IMO, fixtures are easier. I had a very small project in which I used Factories and it was just plain difficult to use, setting up inheritance for users, admin users, employer user, etc etc. Fixtures were much easier.

Comment: @Marnen Laibow-Koser, assertions of 'dangerous', 'cumbersome', etc. require explanation to be anything other than opinion.

Comment: @PeterDeWeese I believe I explained those terms in my [comment above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7588868/has-many-through-in-fixtures-in-rails-3-1/7823054#comment13027682_7823054). Got further questions?

Comment: @pcg79 I think the folks at 37Signals are among the few people who still use fixtures (none of the many Rails projects I've worked on has used them, except one that I did before I knew better). In general I think that, while the Rails core team did a great job, there are some areas of Rails that they got wrong. Fixtures are one of those areas. As for fixtures being easier to use than factories, I'd say the reverse is true. But it really doesn't matter: fixtures make your tests unsafe and unreliable, for the reasons I've already explained. I don't think that's worth any perceived ease of use.

Comment: @pcg79 BTW, I'd be curious to see the specific scenario for which you found fixtures easier. My experience has been that when people find fixtures easier to use than factories, it's because they're trying to use factories like fixtures (which, not surprisingly, doesn't work well at all).

Comment: This was a two year old project so it's entirely possible that things have improved. The specific scenario involved just trying to create tests for our multiple user types.  Creating Factories so was much more complicated than a simple 8 line yml file that it really bordered on ridiculous.  I'll make you a promise tho - next project I'll go Factories and see if it's any better now.

Comment: @pcg79 Hmm. I don't see how you could do that with fixtures in only 8 lines, or why you'd need *either* fixtures or factories if the tests were *that* simple.

Comment: user:
  name: $LABEL
  type: $LABEL
  
admin:
  name: $LABEL
  type: $LABEL

Comment: See?  Pretty simple.  So if our tests are simple enough, may we use fixtures?

Comment: @pcg79 My answer to that depends on what the test code is doing with those records. A factory implementation, though, would be no harder to set up and would scale better: the moment you add anything else to your example, it gets too complex for fixtures. So while you could get away with the bad practice of fixtures in this case, I wouldn't advise it.

Comment: This is getting silly.  I can tell you from extensive experience that *things do not get too complex for fixtures*.  I'm going to go ahead and leave it at that. You don't like them, I get it.  But your use of absolutes is both wrong and confusing for new developers, thus my downvote.

Comment: @pcg79 Also, I can tell you from extensive experience that things *do* get too complex for fixtures -- at least, if you're testing properly. It's *very* hard, if not impossible, to test properly if you're using fixtures.

Comment: LOL @ bad practice.  Please post a blog post somewhere that explains why.  You really haven't posted enough (or any really) proof of any of your claims in your original answer. All I can tell, Marnen, from this discussion is that either I'm a better programmer than you (unlikely) or you're wrong about fixtures.

Comment: @pcg79 I've written at length about fixtures on the Rails list; a simple archive search will get you started. I also explained at (shorter) length above -- are you not seeing that answer, or is that not sufficient? Fixtures are always *bad practice* because they *separate* your test data from the tests that use that data (unlike factories, where the records are created explicitly in every test). They are *bad practice* because they have a tendency to be non-specific to particular tests; thus, they leak state between tests and create the possibility of false positives.

Comment: @pcg79 In addition, except in the simplest of cases, fixtures are *less convenient* than factories. These are facts. Ignore them at your peril. I note that you're not presenting any explanation for your side of the argument, except a toy example that doesn't really show much of anything.

Comment: @Marnen Laibow-Kose, yes you answered my question (quite well) -- thanks.

Comment: I have a rails 2.3.x project that I am migrating to rails 3.x. While I like FactoryGirl, and have used it on newer projects, I don't have the allocated time to rewrite my test suite for the legacy project.

Comment: @rwc9u Then you're creating technical debt. You'll have to pay it at some point.

Comment: So @Marnen you propose not only doing the complete rails upgrade from 2.3 to 3.x, but also rewriting your test suite during that same process?

Comment: @rwc9u I suggest rewriting your test suite, and upgrading Rails. What order you do it in is pretty much immaterial. The point is that you have two upgrades you need to make, so allot the time to do both at some point.

Comment: Good coverage of both fixtures and factories: https://whatdoitest.com/getting-friendly-with-fixtures  Upshot: fixtures work well for a lot of projects.  Intolerance usually comes from ignorance.

Comment: @bronson Not in this case. My intolerance of fixtures comes from actual experience with them, and thereby realizing that they're an entirely incorrect and inadequate solution for test data: they define the test data too far away from where that data is used; thus, you have action at a distance and inflexibility. The article you linked to, however, *was* written from a position of ignorance. The author doesn't understand how to use factories properly, and doesn't understand the true disadvantages of fixtures.

Comment: @MarnenLaibow-Koser I'm using fixtures right now in a project and they're great.  Fast, easy to edit, complete.  It's not a trivial project either, 12 models.  Lots of Rails projects use fixtures without suffering.  At best, you're being amazingly intolerant and, at worst, you're flat out wrong.

Comment: @MarnenLaibow-Koser action-at-a-distance is solved by fixture helpers i.e. users(:sherman).  Heck, most factory projects I've seen define their data in /spec/factories/*.rb, which is no better than fixtures.  And it's just as easy to define inflexible factories as inflexible fixtures.  These are both tools that work when used correctly.  Please tone down the religion?

Comment: @bronson Fixture helpers don't help, in my experience. The problem is that you need to define in your fixture files every record that you want to use. That's tedious, so you'll either wind up with bloated fixture files or imprecise test data. There's simply no reason to do that that I can see, when you could just be creating your test records on the fly with factories. Fixtures *look like* they work well, but don't provide you with good, flexible test data. I'm sorry you can't see how they're hurting you, but they *are* hurting you.

Comment: @bronson "most factory projects I've seen define their data in /spec/factories/*.rb, which is no better than fixtures"—Agreed; that's no better than fixtures. It's also not the proper way to use factories. The factory files define record *templates*; then you customize them as necessary to create individual records. Most factory projects I've seen were created by people who know this. When I see fixture-like factories on a project I'm on, I replace them with proper factories.

Comment: You realize you can use fixtures as templates too, don't you?  Fixtures and factories are just not as different as you seem to think.  I'm sorry how you can't see how your bigotry is hurting you, but it is hurting you.</quote>  I'm not interested in pursuing this any further, hope you have a more open mind in the future.

Comment: @bronson How would you use a fixture as a template? I can't think of a way without being extremely kludgey. But if that is possible, it actually removes some of my objects. As for my mind being open, it absolutely is—hence this question; however, an open mind doesn't mean I think all approaches are equally good.

Comment: Just down-voted because I believe this answer does a disservice to new programmers or programmers looking to incrementally improve their rails applications without adding much more complexity. Your flat out rejection is of no use and doesn't answer the question asked. I've been developing rails applications for almost 10 years now, including very large projects that host millions of users. Fixtures definitely have their place and can be an excellent tool for certain test cases.

Comment: @JeremyBaker If a programmer wants to want to incrementally improve his application without adding more complexity, removing fixtures is actually a pretty good way of doing that. Fixtures have no place in any Rails project, and are not appropriate for *any* test case -- factories can do everything fixtures do, but without the disadvantage. If you don't understand that, I'm sorry for you, but don't drag the rest of us down with you.

Answer (score 9):

Assuming you want or have to stick with fixtures, then if you switch from an HABTM to a has_many :through relationship, then you can no longer use the short inline lists. You must create a separate fixture file for the :through model.

Comment: I have a fixture users.yml, cities.yml and city_users.yml. How do I tell my tests that a user has many cities using these fixtures?

Comment: Danny, this is how: http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/classes/ActiveRecord/Fixtures.html#label-has_and_belongs_to_many

(a year late...)

Comment: And, exactly right rwc9u. The Rails team figures that the only reason you'd ever use HMT over HABTM is if your join table includes additional information. Since you'll need to put the additional information in your fixtures, there's little point to having a shortcut.

Gotta say, I agree... I can't think of any shortcut that's any better than just explicitly specifying the joins.